# How can I control my Kivy scrollview by dragging the sliders?

Tags: python, user-interface, scrollview, kivy

I am new to Kivy and while I love the touch interface, I want my code to work well on non-touchscreen computers as well.

Right now I have a scrollview with a gridlayout in it that is larger than the visible area. I can very easily move my view by swiping my screen or clicking and dragging with my mouse on the background. What I want to add is a conventional click and drag function to my scroll bar (like the scroll bar on the right side of your browser window).

I don't need the little up and down arrows, but I would like to be able to drag the scroll bar and move across my scrollview.

I am new both to SO and Kivy/Python, so I apologize if this is a bad question or poorly worded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do a such thing :
in a ScrollView there's a scroll_type property, so by setting it up, you can achieve what you want to do.

http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html?highlight=scroll_type#kivy.uix.scrollview.ScrollView.scroll_type

you might want to change the bar_width property if you set the scroll_type=['bars'], because it default to 2 and it's too small to grab with a mouse

here's an example based on the one in the docs:

```
layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
# Make sure the height is such that there is something to scroll.
layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
for i in range(30):
    btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
    layout.add_widget(btn) 
root = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400),
                scroll_type=['bars'], bar_width='10dp') #you can use both ['bars','content']
root.add_widget(layout)
```

you can skim over the docs to see what else you can change based on your own needs .

Comment: The behaviour of the scrollbar seems really odd with a mouse.  I have to click and drag down the scrollbar to shift it up and vice versa.  Is there any way to change this default behaviour? EDIT: Changing to scroll_type = ['bars','content'] does the trick.